# Can't disable redshift

Tags: 14.04, process

A few weeks ago I installed the redshift application using:

```
sudo apt-get install redshift redshift-gtk
```

I've faced a lot of bugs with it, including not being able to disable it. It finally got to the point tonight where I uninstalled it, using:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge redshift redshift-gtk
```

However, my screen is still tinted red. Doing the below removes no processes:

```
chris@pc:~$ sudo killall redshift
redshift: no process found
chris@pc:~$ sudo killall redshift-gtk
redshift-gtk: no process found
```

Looking through `htop` I can't see anything resembling redshift, although I may be overlooking something.

How can I end this once and for all? I'd rather avoid rebooting as I have a lot of applications open and I'd like to not have to reopen my workflow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What Redshift does is to set the colour temperature of your screen from 6500 (normal color temperature) to 3700 ("night"  setting for Redshift).

What probably happened is that you removed the application while your screen was set to 3700. By removing Redshift, it was left in that state.

#### What you need to do

You have two options:

- Try to set the colour temperature of your screen back, manually, to 6500 (via the button menu that most screens have)

or

- Reinstall Redshift; don't run the interface, but set the temperature from command line:

  ```
  redshift -O 6500
  ```

  Then uninstall redshift again.

Either one of these options should work.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I'm confused about how redshift sets the temperature, though, as my cursor doesn't get affected my redshift I was assuming it was modifying the image before it's sent to the monitor rather than altering the colour temperature on the monitor itself. Regardless, it's sorted. :)

Comment: @JohnDorean Yes, Redshift does color temperature adjustment at the graphics stack level. The mouse cursor is "hardware accelerated", meaning it's processed by the graphics hardware directly without any software processing, that's why it doesn't get affected. See this [F.A.Q](https://justgetflux.com/faq.html) and this [link](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3436/46710).

Answer (score 17):

You can now use [`redshift -x`](https://www.mankier.com/1/redshift#-x) to reset everything:

> `-x` Reset mode (remove adjustment from screen).

Comment: I joined this community just to upvote this.  Don't know why this was downvoted.  This solved the issue for me!

Comment: Yea.. Hi guys! I logged into my account now too which took quite some effort for me now... Yea its great comment no doubt... But when refering to the question... The problem is that it automaticaly turns back into temperatur adjusted mode so "redshift -x" will help you for about 2 seconds and then your screen is color temperatur adjusted again... Welcome to the community :)

Comment: Worked permanently for me :)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to disable Redshift is to go to Settings>Startup applications, and than to put Redshift on “off” (or remove it from the startup applications list),  and now reboot the computer. Redshift will be off. If you will like to start it again – 
just click the icon and it will start.
To find the right color temperature - watch this link:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/protect-eyes-redshift-linux/