# How do I kill redshift?

Tags: process, kill, system-monitor, redshift

I have installed redshift using apt-get.

I started it up in a terminal window, and then accidentally killed the terminal. Redshift did not stop running itself. My screen is most certainly still under the influence of redshift.

I open Linux Mint system monitor, and I could not find anything that I thought was redshift. Certainly not anything named redshift.

So how do I go about killing redshift?

Comment: Do `ps -A | grep redshift` to see if it is still running. If yes than you also get the Process ID (the first number) than do `sudo kill -9 <Process ID>`. There are certainly faster and beautiful one-liners to kill a process by name ;) but this should do it also

Comment: the process name must not be redshift, because the grep did not return anything. But redshift is most certainly still running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the clue in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/561389/423684).

Seems that redshift is not running anymore since you killed the terminal BUT the last screen settings keep being there constantly.

So you have to reset your screen manually. I'm citing:

> You have two options:
>
> Try to set the colour temperature of your screen back, manually, to
>   6500 (via the button menu that most screens have)
>
> or
>
> Reinstall Redshift; don't run the interface, but set the temperature
>   from command line:
>
> ```
> redshift -O 6500
> ```
>
> Then uninstall redshift again.
>
> Either one of these options should work.

So in your case if you want to keep redshift anyway you don't have to reinstall and uninstall it. Just use the command

```
redshift -O 6500
```

to reset the display color.

Comment: This is correct. Because yesterday I noticed I WAS able to find the redshift process while the terminal was open.

Answer (score 13):

To have the screen colour return to normal, type this in Terminal:

```
redshift -x
```

From [the documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/redshift.1.html):

```
-x    Reset mode (remove adjustment from screen).
```

Comment: This was straight forward and still works.

Comment: In case of bspwm (bspwmrc) I am using: `redshift -x && redshift &`, because every restart it starts over with no problem. Of course I have all settings on `~/.config/redshift/redshift.conf`

Answer (score 2):

use redshift -h to see all the available flag but there is no such flag to stop or kill it. The way I have killed the process is below

pidof redshift
kill -9 id_from_previous_command

id_from_previous_command will be the id of the process
-9 is for killing the process immediately

Comment: This actually works.

Comment: Glad it helped, I have uninstalled RedShift completely and now using Ubuntu's native functionality for a night light