# Colors on one monitor appearing far darker

Tags: monitor

I've got two monitors. One's the laptop's built-in, one's external.

My laptop monitor's colors are far darker, and I'd like them to match my external monitor's colors.

Where are the settings to do so?

Comment: Do you mean you want to increase brightness? Laptops usually have dedicated keys. Different display panels may have slightly different colors, it in not uncommon. There are no settings to make all pannels have the same colors.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different displays look differently. Esp. when they use different technology, like OLED and TFT. Your laptop and your monitor will have a configuration with special button combinations. E.g. you can make your laptop brighter or your monitor darker, refer to the vendor documentation of the device.

It may be that you laptop cannot get brighter, in that case you need to make your monitor darker for matching both. Same for color or contrast, usually the range of your monitor will be wider than the range on your laptop (not in all cases), so it's about making your monitor look worse then, and not making your laptop look better, if both should look more equal.

Note that there are dynamic changes, e.g. a laptop can change its brightness depending on the energy setting (with / without power adapter connected). Also there are time of day dependent modes that make the screen more yellow in the evening, so at day both are equal but at night one might look more orange.

However, the best way is called "color calibration", which is a normal process for people doing design work on a computer. This will get you the best results: [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrate-screen.html.en). However, you need special equipment for color calibration.

Summary:

- Open the energy settings and disable dynamic brightness [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-autobrightness.html.en), [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-brightness.html.en)
- Disable redshift night mode [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561373/cant-disable-redshift/561389#561389)
- Adjust the brightness and color (!) of your screen using the screen buttons.
- Adjust the brightness of your laptop using special buttons (e.g. FN-Key and a sun-icon)
- Done that, afterwards start a screen calibration if necessary. See link [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrate-screen.html.en).

Answer (score 1):

To control the brightness you can use [`xrandr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xrandr.1.html):

```bsh
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 0.50
```

In output you have to type your output device, to find out:

```bsh
xrandr --query
```

In brightness you have to type a value from 0(dark) to 2(super bright), 1 is normal.